# Php isset $_GET not working as expected

Tags: php, session-variables, getvalue

I'm trying to pass `$user_domain` to `login.php`. I get the value from `first_page.php` from `header();`. In `returning_user.php` I set a variable `$_SESSION['returning_user']` to let my program know what to do in `login.php`. If everything goes well, the user stays on `login.php`. If something goes wrong, the user is redirected to `first_page.php` and must resubmit form. The problem I'm facing right now is that the user is being returned to `first_page.php` when I include `returning_user.php` inside `login.php`. When I remove it, the user stays on `login.php` but it seems the code between the `if()` statement is not being executed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**first_page.php**

```
//rest of code above
if($stmt){
header("Location: returning_user.php?domain=".$domain."&key=".$key."");
exit;
}
```

**returning_user.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['key'])  && isset($_GET['domain']) ){

//get domain variable
$user_domain = $_GET['domain'];

//put key variable in session
$_SESSION['user_domain'] = $user_domain;

//create a returning_user session
$_SESSION['returning_user']="TRUE";

//direct user to login page
header("location:../login.php");
exit;

}else{
 header("location : first_page.php");
 exit;
   }
```

**login.php**

```
 session_start();
 include 'returning_user.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['returning_user']) && $_SESSION['returning_user']=="TRUE"){
    //do something amazing here
}
```

**var_dump($_GET)**

```
array(2) { ["domain"]=> string(10) "mydomain" ["key"]=> string(7) "7024158" }
```

Comment: So what does `var_dump($_GET)` tell you?

Comment: My opinion is, that the values of the `$domain`and `$key` are the problem. So, as @MatsLindh kindly asked, you should provide us an output of the `$_GET` array. If you ignore our comments, then how do you expect from us to help you?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't buy the accepted answer. What's the value of both GET arrays/variables? I see `$domain` and `$user_domain` and to me, this tells me of something not being defined correctly. I've tested your code with sample values and it didn't fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: After testing the code, you are right the problem is not in returning.php but in login.php

Comment: @MatsLindh : I did a `var_dump($_GET)` in `returning_user.php` and I got `array(2) { ["domain"]=> string(10) "mydomain" ["key"]=> string(7) "7024158" } ` so it's not empty

Comment: @aendeerei: I have updated the post

Comment: `include(returning_user.php);` if that's the actual syntax, it's erroring out and would have most likely thrown an undefined constant notice. It needs to be wrapped in quotes `include('returning_user.php');` and the session should be started if it wasn't and inside all pages using sessions. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to see if it does return an error. `exit;` should also be used after header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Thanks. I just updated everything here and I've performed tests in my program. I'm using error reporting but nothing gets reported. The `login.php` is really the problem it executes the else statement in `returning_user.php` and sends me back to `first_page.php`. If I change `login.php` to `somerandom.php` and do not `include('returning_user.php');` I get redirected there with the variables without problems. If I remove the file in `login.php` it executes but I need the file to protect `login.php`. I dont know what im doing wrong here.

Comment: @BalloonFight Use error reporting like this: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: @BalloonFight Since the problem seems to persist and there are more files involved, then it would be better to present whole codes and to describe the workflow better. For this reedit your question and append the new things.

Comment: @aendeerei: Thanks. Ive updated everything. Ill be running more tests.

Comment: `returning_user.php` redirects and exits on all code branches. The code after `include 'returning_user.php';` never runs; it doesn't have any chance to do anything amazing.

Comment: @axiac: I guess you're the one who downvoted me. I've been programming for up to 12 hours today dude. So at this point my brain is pure mash. You mean to remove exit? Can you provide something please? Thanks.

Comment: @BalloonFight I was unclear. My appology for that. I meant you to give the general workflow of the app (regarding the 3 files), not to describe the code steps which you implemented - since we already understand them. Anyway, I provided an alternative solution. If it helps you then I'm glad. If not, well, we try further ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BEFORE:**

Your code have a problem, which I'll try to explain:

- You, the user, are on the `first_page.php`.
- From there you are redirected to `returning_user.php`. The GET values ("domain" and "key") are passed too.
- `returning_user.php` reads the GET values (which are now SET), writes them to session and redirects you to `login.php` (WITHOUT passing the GET values too). ***Note***: Technically you are passing two GET values to a page (`returning_user.php`) in order to save them there in session. This step is in my opinion not needed; you could have saved them in session directly in the `first_page.php`.
- In `login.php` the page `returning_user.php` is included. It tries to read the GET values again. But, because the GET values are NOT ANYMORE SET, you are redirected to `first_page.php`.

Another problem is the one described by @MatsLindh.

**AFTER:**

So I gave some thoughts about what you want to achieve, and I came with the following solution:

- You, the user, are on the `first_page.php`.
- You complete a form and submit it.
- Upon submit, the values "domain", "key" and "returning_user" are written into session.
- Then you are redirected to `login.php`.
- In `login.php` a file named `protector.php` is included. `protector.php` checks if the session values "domain" and "key" are set. If not, a redirect to `first_page.php` takes place.
- If the validation of the session variables in `protector.php` is successful, then the further codes in `login.php` can be processed. Like: read the session variable "returning_user" and *do something amazing there* :-)

**Notes:**

- You can see `protector.php` as replacer for your `returning_user.php`.
- You can include `protector.php` in all pages which need to be "protected".
- I would have renamed `first_page.php` to `dashboard.php`.
- In `first_page.php` I implemented a form, in order to be able to display something on screen in case of a redirect from another page to `first_page.php` and to start the redirect to `login.php` upon clicking on a button, e.g. upon form submission.

Good luck!

#### first_page.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// Operations upon form submit.
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    $stmt = TRUE;
    $domain = 'mydomain';
    $key = '7024158';

    if ($stmt) {
        $_SESSION['domain'] = $domain;
        $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
        $_SESSION['returning_user'] = 1; // Don't use 'TRUE'.

        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <title>Demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .header, .section { padding: 10px; }
            .header { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
            .section div { padding-bottom: 10px; }
            .section button { padding: 10px; color: #fff; border: none; width: 200px; background-color: #269abc; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="header">
            <h3>
                Welcome! You are on the first page ;-)
            </h3>
        </header>

        <section class="section">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    Here comes some form content...
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submitButton">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### protector.php

```
<?php

session_start();

// Check domain and key.
if (!isset($_SESSION['domain']) || !isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
    header('Location: first_page.php');
    exit;
}
```

#### login.php

```
<?php

require_once 'protector.php';

echo 'Page validation successful.';
echo '<br/><br/>';

if (isset($_SESSION['returning_user']) && $_SESSION['returning_user']) {
    echo 'I will do something amazing here...';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `domain` contains a `?`, it breaks the `&key` variable.

You should change your `first_page.php` to

```
if($stmt){
    header("Location: returning_user.php?domain=". urlencode($domain)."&key=".$key."");
}
```

Comment: My bad. Should be `urlencode`. Without the underscore. See my edit,

Comment: What about `$key`? It produces the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `include 'returning_user.php';` in `login.php`, the code in `returning_user.php` runs. If you follow that code path from the top, you can see that regardless of the contents of the any parameters, the end result is a redirect - either to `login.php` a directory down (.. these paths seem weird, as that means that the `login.php` you've added is not the same `login.php` as you're redirecting the user to) or to `first_user.php`.

I'm not sure you actually wanted to do `include 'returning_user.php';` - it seems you've based everything else on that page setting up a session and then redirecting the user to the destination, instead of having the file being included (and when it's being included like that, you're importing the variables into the current scope - no need for a session for something like that).

Comment: It works when I remove the `returning_user.php` from `login.php`. But just like you've figured out, I'm trying to use `returning_user.php` like we use a `session.php` to protect pages from being accessible from the browser. If I remove `returning_user.php`, the workflow works but `login.php` is no longer protected. Maybe I'm not understanding how to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

I see your frustration. For a start, you DO need to remove returning_user.php from Login.

Then, replace your code with this in login, with this:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['returning_user'] == "TRUE")){
echo "Success!";
}
```

Also (and this is generally an unpopular opinion), to avoid using headers, which can cause other problems elsewhere, I much prefer to end my PHP tag, and place the following Javascript

```
 <script>location.replace("whatever.php");</script>
```

And then pick my PHP tag up immediately after.

Comment: But I dont want people to be able to access `login.php` from the browser. It is a protected page.